# ifconfig bridge on macos - BRDGADD en0: Resource busy

Tags: ifconfig

Anyone know how to createa bridge network interface on MacOS v12.4 Mon?

I have tried:

```
sudo ifconfig bridge7 create
sudo ifconfig bridge7 addm en0
sudo ifconfig bridge7 up
```

In step two I get this:

```
ifconfig: BRDGADD en0: Resource busy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: see [the Apple Support article "Bridge virtual network interfaces on Mac"](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/bridge-virtual-network-interfaces-on-mac-mh43557/mac).

Long answer: On macOS, you generally shouldn't use `ifconfig` to modify the network setup; that'll change the "live" interface state, but it tends to get overwritten by the system configuration daemon (`configd`) setting things to the way *it* thinks they should be. Instead, use `networksetup` or the System Preferences utility to change the system config database, and let `configd` apply those changes to the live network state.

Unfortunately, `networksetup` doesn't seem to have options to create and manage bridge interfaces, so you'll need to use System Preferences:

1. On your Mac, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Network.
2. Click the Action pop-up menu ("..." or gear icon), then choose Manage Virtual Interfaces.
3. Click the Add button (+), choose New Bridge, then select the interfaces to include in the bridge.
4. Click Create, then click Done.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, you can not see the bridge in the terminal when created using the settings/network ui?

Comment: @ChrisG. That's strange, it works for me (though I don't have a Monterey system to test with, I tried it under Catalina). I have a pre-built Thunderbolt Bridge interface (bridge0), and when I create a new one it shows up as bridge1 in the `ifconfig` listing.

Comment: Thanks, really glad for info - I will try in one other machine to test it again, and come back.

Comment: Hmm, every time I try to add a bridge the connection goes down on the interface.